# Splitting a String array and storing in a list

Tags: java

There is a `string[] arr = {"aa-bb-cc","dd-bb-ee","aa-hh-gg"}` which needs to be split on the basis of , and -. The values `aa,dd,aa` should be stored in one list whereas `bb,hh` in another list. I have written this code snippet:

```
String[] arr = {"aa-bb-cc","dd-bb-ee","aa-hh-gg"};      
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){          
    newArr =  arr[i].split(",");            
    for(int j=0;j<newArr.length;j++){               
    resultArr = newArr[j].split("-");                                                
    appList.add(resultArr[0]);               
    prodList.add(resultArr[1]);                 
    rolList.add(rresultArr[2]ol);        
}
```

> Above approach could be better if we do `arr[i]`.split in another way so that we can run only one loop but I could not achieve that so far.

I wanted to know is there any best way to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Splitting by `,` wont do much, since here it seperates the elements in the array...

Comment: @Harleen: considering that you are new on SO, whichever answer helped you solve your problem, you should mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! @SarthakMittal .

Comment: What could be the best way to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException if say newArr[1] or newArr[2] is not available. I can very well handle in catch but I want the better way that there would be less chances to get such runtime exceptions.

Comment: @Harleen you can loop the array through its length, but then you will either have to use if-else or switch-case inside your loop, so it is better that you create an array of ArrayList which would contain appList, prodList and rolList and access them with the loop index...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to split it using `,` ,since it's not part of the String but part of the String array declaration syntax,just split it with a `-`

```
String[] arr = {"aa-bb-cc","dd-bb-ee","aa-hh-gg"};      
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){          
newArr =  arr[i].split("-");                                                            
appList.add(newArr[0]);               
prodList.add(newArr[1]);                 
rolList.add(newArr[2]);        
}
```

Comment: Ya. This is the way to go